# What is current state of MX Emulation?

Tags: apache-royale

I confess that I didn't have much time to follow every release of Apache Royale but my question is: What is the state of Apache Royale MX Emulation ?

Can I convert and application with buttons, grids, alerts, etc ... ?
The skin was implemented or is a wireframes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check and see in what state Emulation components are is to try them yourself. AFAIK lot's of them are just displaying simple Div, so they need definitely more love in terms of UI. 
In order to see what classes from Flex has been part of Emulation components effort you can look to file [MXRoyaleClasses.as](https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/blob/develop/frameworks/projects/MXRoyale/src/main/royale/MXRoyaleClasses.as) in Royale repository. The second step would be look into [RoyaleTourDeFlex](http://apacheroyaleci.westus2.cloudapp.azure.com:8080/job/TourDeFlexMigration/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/examples/mxroyale/tourdeflexmodules/bin/js-debug/index.html) which is an Example of how [TourDeFlex](http://flex.apache.org/tourdeflex/index.html) was ported to Royale using those components. Of course [source code](https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/tree/develop/examples/mxroyale/tourdeflexmodules) of RoyaleTourDeFlex is part of framework repository.

Comment: So, the RoyaleTourDeFlex is always updated with the current Emulation progress ?

From what I saw, it's still far behind flex in terms of UI.

Comment: It is definitely not finished in terms of UI, but in general it always use the newest build of Royale. RoyaleTourDeFlex is just an example what you can accomplish with Emulation components. You are more than welcome improve those components etc.

Comment: I think I have point you in case of list of MX components in Royale to wrong file. Take a look here what is currently emulated: https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/blob/develop/frameworks/projects/MXRoyale/src/main/resources/mx-royale-manifest.xml

Comment: At some point, I may be forced to abandon AIR and I would like to have a backup plan. On this case seems that move to Royale is the best option and seems that I have 2 options: 1. MX Emulation; 2. Jowel. MX Emulation would be the prefer option, however seems to behind to be finished. Jowel is pretty and don't have to deal with compatibility issues however it's a totally refactoring and a "admin panel style demo application will definitely help a lot for beginners".

Comment: What do you mean by "admin panel style demo application" ? We have [TourDeJewel](https://royale.apache.org/tourdejewel/#) - is it not enough ? 
It depends how much of your code is free from Flash API - if your code has good separation - business logic (pure AS3) and UI - you will have to rewrite UI only.

Comment: Yes, I have my UI separated from business logic. admin panel: https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-templates

Comment: You should be good than in case of path where you would like to rewrite UI part to Jewel. Emulation component simply involve probably your more influence in Framework code. It could have big advantage, cause you will better know framework, most likely you will have to fix Emulation components which requires pull requests etc. You may able to gain committer rights. IMO even if you go with Jewel you may have to fix some stuff inside framework. :)

Comment: Hi Hugo, can you share a draft drawn with boxes about what you consider ""admin panel style demo application"? (can be done with paper/pencil or with some prototype tool), that could be shared in mailing list. and can help to know what you have in mind. and maybe we can do some example depending of the needs. Thanks